# Is there any equivalent of SQLBulkCopy in Npgsql

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, npgsql

After some goоgling, I could not find a proper replacement of SQLBulkCopy from SQLClient in Npgsql. Can any body suggest me anything like SQLBulkCopy for PostgreSQL? I need to insert around 10 millions of data.. I know about making single query insertion...

I am just doing test for comparison purpose.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Very old now, but note that Npgsql 3 includes an optimized binary bulk copy functionality, see [the docs (3.0)](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/3.0/copy.html).

Comment: That's horrible. Are you sure there isn't anything that encapsulates that with a DbDataReader source?